# while retreving the data using ajax getting an error message

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, x-cart

I posting my value through ajax and using the response the details will be displayed.I am getting the problem while retreiving the data.But i dono where i have mistaked,then this is the error getiing displayed frequently 
              "There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n";

```
   in all browsers mainly in the chrome,could any one help me...
```

this is my code,

```
var xmlHttp;

try {
    // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e) {
    // Internet Explorer 6+
    try {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        // Internet Eplorer 5
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX. Download a newer browser to view this page.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

// insert server response into HTML element
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            MM_check_session(xmlHttp.responseText);
            var b_gc = document.getElementById(insert).value;
            document.getElementById(insert).value = xmlHttp.responseText;
            var shippingid = getCheckedValue('checkout_form', 'shippingid');
            closeMessage();
            MM_calc_shipping(shippingid);
            if (b_gc == xmlHttp.responseText) {
                MM_register();
            } else {
                error = 1;
                document.getElementById('payment_error').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById(insert).value = '';
            }
        } else {
            closeMessage();
            alert("We can't process your request.Please refresh(reload) the page to proceed further:\n"
                    + xmlHttp.statusText);
        }

    }
}
displayStaticMessage(
        '<img src=' + config_MM_loader_image_path + ' alt=\'loading...Please wait\'>',
        false);

xmlHttp.open("POST", serverScript, true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type',
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-length', parameters.length);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
xmlHttp.send(parameters);
```

any help

Comment: Can't find any place in your code where you produce mentioned error message ("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n";).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be incorrectly tagged as php. Also have you considered jQuery for the ease of ajax whilst using it.

as for your question could you post the code on the page where the ajax request is going to as the code here looks fine..

Edit:
Where is serverScript set?
change serverScript for the ajax page you are calling?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx